# Can Intellij checkout GitHub private repos?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can you use the Intellij IDEA to checkout the GitHub private repos?

I can't pass the test.

Comment: I'm having the same issue -- login credentials set up correctly, IntelliJ's Test button makes sure of that, can clone from public repositories just fine... my private repositories both fail.

Comment: Maybe add the exact error description. I get "Repository test has failed". Not very helpful though...

Comment: Might also help people to diagnose the problem if you add what form of authentication you use (e.g., token) and whether two-factor authentication is activated on github. (For me with the same problem: using token, 2FA activated, everything works fine for public repos)

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA should be able to checkout GitHub private repos the same way as it does public repos. You just need to provide login credentials.